# git list files and folders with last changed commit

Tags: git

I'm looking for a sort of `git ls` - a command with output similar to the github repo view - which would ideally output something like this:

```
$ git ls
uncommitted.txt
folder/          abcd0123  Changed a file in a folder  Sat Aug 13 00:01:06 2016 +0200
oldfile.txt      abcd3210  Changed an old file         Sat Aug 13 00:08:23 2016 +0200
```

Does something like this exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any ready-made `git ls` so I went ahead and made one myself:

https://github.com/jnvsor/git-ls

Answer (score 2):

### git ls-tree & git log:

```
commited_files=$(git ls-tree master --name-only)
uncommited_files=$(git status --porcelain | grep "??" | sed -e 's/^?? //')
list="$commited_files $uncommited_files"
for file in $list; do
  echo $(printf "$file: "; git log --pretty=format:'%h %s %ad' -1 $file);
done
```

This makes a list that is all the files and folders in your active directory. If you want to recursively do this, them just do `git ls-tree -r master --name-only`.

You then iterate through each file that you have in your list, and print the log of the last commit for that file.

Comment: This is close, but I want to see uncommited files too - I've written a script of my own that's using a similar principle

Comment: Please look at the edit to see if this works for you.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong but wouldn't that cause a problem if a file had a space in it?

Comment: Yes it would. [There are technical reasons for not using space characters in file names](http://superuser.com/q/29111). And if possible you should not use them. Use @JV's answer it is well done. If his doesn't handle that you should fix that case and send a pull request for him.